# bootstrap rows spanning to 12 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a 2 row column as can be seen here.https://codepen.io/centem/pen/bojLLb

Why doesn't the green and blue span to the same length as the yellow block? The yellow block is set to "col-md-12". How do I get it to span the same length?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 block1">
      </br></br></br></br>
      </br></br></br></br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 block2">
          </br></br></br></br>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 block3">
         </br></br></br></br>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 block4">
      </br></br></br></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: col-md-6 = 1/2 so you divide row per half and than again half per half. You need to use col-md-12 to get 1/1 in col-md-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both rows are the same width.  Your problem is you are creating rows inside of rows.  Once you do that it obeys the 12 columns rule again.  So you need to change those to `col-md-12`.

See in my codepen here:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/qPyoNQ

And you can see more information on it in their documentation under the "Two columns with two nested columns" section:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Comment: Eric G. Thank you very much for your help and documentation reference. I fixed it per your codepen reference.